# making sql query compatible for case sensitive collation

Tags: sql-server, collation, case-sensitive

In a project I have a large number of stored procedures (SQL Server). A client tried to run that with `Turkish_CS_AI` collation. It turns out a lot of stored procedures were written without considering the case, so for such case sensitive collation there were so many errors.

Is there a way to run the script/procedures in case sensitive collation without correcting the cases? Here is the snapshot of the error I got.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: And now you've learned always to test your app on a case sensitive collation

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools can find the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the database Collation on client server to match to your Collation settings.

ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest
COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC;
GO